# about mask in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mask

I'm applying a phone-number jQuery mask to a text input in HTML. I need to fix the country code, and follow the amount of digit like: +593 __-___-____

At first, I tried with the following mask:

```
$("#id_text-input").mask("+59399-999-9999");
```

But here, the digit `9` represents meta-data for the mask that matches with any digit. Therefore, the mask in the input is shown like: +5_3__-___-____.

Now, I need that the digit `9` in the country code be fixed.

I try change the mask definition by the digit `9`:

```
$.mask.definitions['9'] = '[9]';
$("#id_text-input").mask("+59399-999-9999");
```

But, this approach also shows me the same mask in the input +5_3__-___-____, where the digits available to write in the text input only can be `9`.

I tried changing the custom options, as [explained here](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/), with a mask like following:

```
var custom_options = {
        byPassKeys: [8, 0, 37, 38, 39, 40],
        watchDataMask: true,
        translation: {
                    '0': {pattern: /\d/},
                    //'9': {pattern: /\d/, optional: false},
                    '#': {pattern: /\d/, recursive: true},
                    'A': {pattern: /[a-zA-Z0-9]/},
                    'S': {pattern: /[a-zA-Z]/}
                }
    };
    $("#id_text-input").mask("+59399-999-9999",custom_options);
```

But, this did not work for me, any suggestions?

Comment: Just curious as to where the data is coming from? If it is a UI you have control over, have you considered making the country code its own field? Also consider the number format will vary according to country.

Comment: Hi Andre, great suggetion, but the UI is maked by django form and It very complex  to modify this. There must be a way to do it by jquery. Thank